# Сброс дефолтных стилей компонента Material UI (v.4)

Tags: css, material-ui

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет. Подскажите, как можно сбросить стили у компонента (в моем примере это Link), например, через makeStyles? Чтобы у ссылки были дефолтные браузерные стили, а не материаловские.

Comment: А для чего вы используете mui, если вам не нужны стили от него?

Comment: Вот есть такая необходимость.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужно сделать это только с одной ссылкой то подойдет такой вариант:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    margin: "unset",
    color: "unset"
  },
  underlineHover: {
    textDecoration: "unset"
  }
}));

...

<Link
 href="#"
 classes={{
   root: classes.root,
   underlineHover: classes.underlineHover
 }}
>
   Link
</Link>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-wu-e89l1y

А если требуется поменять для всех ссылок, то необходимо все тоже самое определить глобально в теме.
Но я бы все же посоветовал не использовать стилизованные компоненты когда они должны выглядеть как не стилизованные.